# Visual Studio 2015 - png/gif images are excluded from project by default when pasting into solution explorer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, solution-explorer

I recently noticed that in Visual Studio 2015 when I paste a bunch of images that are of type jpg or png into my solution they are hidden by default and not included in the project.

I would like to know if this is a normal feature of VS2015 since you really can't do anything with images in VS or if something is wrong with my setup.

Comment: What do you mean by "paste ... into my solution"? What exactly did you do?

Comment: copy 3 images from windows explorer and paste into the Content/img folder through visual studio in my MVC5 WebApp. I noticed that .jpg images are automatically included in the project and anything else is not automatically included.

Comment: Tried the same thing: copied 3 images (one .jpg, one .png, and one .gif) from file explorer and pasted into Content/img of a MVC5 project, and they all got included in the project successfully. Maybe you should try again. If the problem remains, it might be one of the many bugs in VS 2015 that happen sporadically.

Comment: I am going to assume it will get fixed in a later update. For now I will manually include into my solution. Thank you for confirming that!